# python 3.8 urllib file:// issue

Tags: urllib, python-3.8

I want to open a local file with `urllib.request.urlopen` with the following code:

```
urllib.request.urlopen('file:///home/parham/.bashrc')
```

But it generates the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):                                                                                                      
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>                                                                                                   
  File "/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/Cellar/python@3.8/3.8.5/lib/python3.8/urllib/request.py", line 222, in urlopen
    return opener.open(url, data, timeout)                                                                                              
  File "/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/Cellar/python@3.8/3.8.5/lib/python3.8/urllib/request.py", line 525, in open
    response = self._open(req, data)                                                                                                    
  File "/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/Cellar/python@3.8/3.8.5/lib/python3.8/urllib/request.py", line 536, in _open
    result = self._call_chain(self.handle_open, 'default',                                                                              
  File "/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/Cellar/python@3.8/3.8.5/lib/python3.8/urllib/request.py", line 502, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)                                                                                                                
  File "/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/Cellar/python@3.8/3.8.5/lib/python3.8/urllib/request.py", line 806, in <lambda>
    meth(r, proxy, type))                                                                                                               
  File "/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/Cellar/python@3.8/3.8.5/lib/python3.8/urllib/request.py", line 834, in proxy_open
    return self.parent.open(req, timeout=req.timeout)                                                                                   
  File "/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/Cellar/python@3.8/3.8.5/lib/python3.8/urllib/request.py", line 531, in open
    response = meth(req, response)                                                                                                      
  File "/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/Cellar/python@3.8/3.8.5/lib/python3.8/urllib/request.py", line 640, in http_response
    response = self.parent.error(                                                                                                       
  File "/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/Cellar/python@3.8/3.8.5/lib/python3.8/urllib/request.py", line 569, in error
    return self._call_chain(*args)                                                                                                      
  File "/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/Cellar/python@3.8/3.8.5/lib/python3.8/urllib/request.py", line 502, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)                                                                                                                
  File "/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/Cellar/python@3.8/3.8.5/lib/python3.8/urllib/request.py", line 649, in http_error_default
    raise HTTPError(req.full_url, code, msg, hdrs, fp)                                                                                  
urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 400: Bad Request
```

Am I doing it right? or the issue is related to `urllib`?

Answer (score 1):

This issue is related to the `shell-proxy` plugin of `oh-my-zsh`. After disabling it everything works as before.